# Implementing Foldable for a Trie

Tags: haskell, trie

I want to make my Trie data structure foldable. The basic data structure looks like this:

```hs
data Trie a = Trie {
    value :: Maybe a,
    children :: [(Char, Trie a)]
} deriving (Show)
```

I tried to implement the Foldable class by defining foldr:

```hs
instance F.Foldable Trie where
    foldr f z (Trie (Just v) children) =
        F.foldr (\a b -> F.foldr f b a) (f v z) children

    foldr f z (Trie Nothing children) =
        F.foldr (\a b -> F.foldr f b a) z children
```

This does not compile with this error:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `Trie a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Trie a -> b
      at Trie.hs:17:5
Expected type: [(Char, a)]
  Actual type: [(Char, Trie a)]
In the third argument of `F.foldr', namely `children'
In the expression:
  F.foldr (\ a b -> F.foldr f b a) (f v z) children
```

However, if I change the type of children to `Map Char (Trie a)`, the Foldable implementation works without a change. I would like to keep the association list for simplicity's sake at the moment. Could you explain to me why foldr behaves differently on a map and an association list?

Comment: Because `[]`'s `Foldable` instance isn't the one you would want if all lists were association lists.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? This is basically my attempt to learn about the type system.

Comment: When you instantiate `foldr` at the list type `[(a,b)]`, it will operate on tuples of type `(a,b)`, whereas if you wanted to think of all lists as association lists, you might expect `foldr` to operate only on the value part, the `b` part. This is exactly what happens when you instantiate `foldr` at the map type `Map a b`: it only operates on the `b`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you are attempting to fold over a list of key-value
pairs, rather than a list of `Trie`s. What you want to do is ignore the `Char`
keys and just fold into each of the child nodes as so

```
foldr f z (Trie (Just v) children) =
    F.foldr (\(_, a) b -> F.foldr f b a) (f v z) children

foldr f z (Trie Nothing children) =
    F.foldr (\(_, a) b -> F.foldr f b a) z children
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the quick answer. I was focusing on the type of children rather than the function definition.